# Get the Base Hostname Using Only JavaScript So Cookies Work Sitewide

Tags: javascript, regex, url, cookies, subdomain

I am looking for a way to take `window.location.hostname` and end up with the base domain name, regardless of situation. So from all of:

```
http://example.domain.com
https://www.example.domain.com
https://www.example.domain.com/stuff/index.php
```

I would end up with:

```
domain.com
```

And from: `example.domain.co.uk/` would result: `domain.co.uk`

I have searched many questions on this topic here on SO and it seems like none ever really result in a complete answer. Some involve using complicated regex that it's hard to tell if wouldn't sometimes fail. And other answers only net a result of `example.domain.com`.

I am utterly floored that there is not just a simple way of getting this value in JavaScript. I am writing a plugin for websites that uses cookies to store user preferences. I am concerned that if a user sets preferences while using the plugin on a page from one hostname, say `one.domain.com`, on the off chance they go to use the plugin on another page hosted on `two.domain.com`, they would need to set their preferences all over again. When I set the cookies, I would like to be able to set them site-wide (at the `domain.com` level). Because this is a plugin, the domain name will not be known and needs to be calculated starting from `window.location.hostname`.

So is there a standard way of arriving at what I'm looking for? Or am I just approaching this the wrong way? I suppose I could just have a configuration setting for the website owner to input their base domain name and get it that way, but I'd prefer not to go that route if possible. And honestly, I'd still like to know how to do this anyway. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.host
```

will return the domain name. But, in your case it would return "example.domain.com".
Then you need to do some manipulation on it, using split function , to get the desired value.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question.  They know they can get that, but they want only the root domain and they don't know how to get ONLY the root domain.

Comment: You are correct. Just wanted to inform that, there is no other way to do the same than this, in Javascript.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, both about the root domain, and in referring to my multiple personalities as, 'they.' My current personality would like to rage a little bit over how this is not something easily attainable in Javascript ;-)